# learning monodevelop and am having trouble getting a messgae box to appear

Tags: c#, linux, monodevelop, gtk#

I am working in monodevelop and learning c#....
I am trying to get a message box to appear but I can't get it to function correctly ...

Here is my code:

```
using System;  
using Gtk;  
using GtkSharp;  

public partial class MainWindow : Gtk.Window  
{
    public MainWindow () : base(Gtk.WindowType.Toplevel)  
    {  
        Build ();  
    }  

    protected void OnDeleteEvent (object sender, DeleteEventArgs a)
    {
        Application.Quit ();
        a.RetVal = true;
    }
    protected virtual void OnButton11ResizeChecked (object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Hello World Again!!");
    }

}
```

What am i missing?

Comment: Note that Winforms itself is largely supported on Linux as well; just make up your mind like the other anwers pointed out

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot mix the GTK# and System.Windows.Forms UI toolkits. You need to use a GTK dialog, something like this:

```
void ShowMessage (Window parent, string title, string message)
{
    Dialog dialog = null;
    try {
        dialog = new Dialog (title, parent,
            DialogFlags.DestroyWithParent | DialogFlags.Modal,
            ResponseType.Ok);
        dialog.VBox.Add (new Label (message));
        dialog.ShowAll ();

        dialog.Run ();
    } finally {
        if (dialog != null)
            dialog.Destroy ();
    }
}
```

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990640/is-there-a-form-showdialog-equivalent-for-gtk-windows/998795#998795).

Comment: why is this so overcomplex ?

Comment: How to get the parent window?

Answer (score 1):

You are referencing GTK which is the bundled graphical toolkit in mono but are trying to use Windows.Forms which, although included in mono too, is a different toolkit:

**System.Windows.Forms:** This is the toolkit used in windows, the implementation on mono "emulates" how this controls are drawn and behave under platforms that mono runs on.

**Gtk:** This is a toolkit used in many OpenSource applications (Firefox, Pidgin, etc) and GTKSharp is simply the implementation of this same library but exposed to the .Net languages available on mono although you could use it directly with Visual Studio or a Microsoft compiler too.

So summarizing, as Mike said, you cannot use them both, you have to choose either one. If you are just learning .Net I would greatly advice to learn GTK instead of Windows Forms. Windows forms is kind of poor and basic toolkit, and soon you'll find that you'll need to learn a new API from a third party to do stuff that windows forms cant do (DevExpress, Infragistics) and Gtk can be easily extended and adjusted to your needs.