# VisualStudio for Mac + GTK - Is it a real product?

Tags: gtk#, visual-studio-mac

I've got a mission to develop a desktop application for both Mac and Windows. Searching for a visual environment, I've found Visual Studio with Gtk as a most promising option.

I have found a very useful documentation for the API [here](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=N%3AGtk).

I could get some basic help from questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4403756/learning-monodevelop-and-am-having-trouble-getting-a-messgae-box-to-appear) one.

I assume that it is tightly related to the [GtkSharp](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/gtksharp/) project.

So I have started to develop, just to find out that there is no significant community support to what I'm doing.

Searching for video tutorials that will demo the creation of UI that is more than two-buttons and and one label gave me nothing. I have registered to the Xamarin University that was promising to provide tutorials, but found nothing there.

I was trying to add more windows, and got them as source-only without a visual editor, and could not find any solution for this.

I have realized that when I will have to capture video from a camera (my current task), I'll find no support for doing it. So I'm suspecting I'll have to find an alternative Python or Java solution.

Can anybody please shed some light on the status of this VS/Gtk project and explain how to get support for it?

Thank you!

Comment: Gtk (& GtkSharp) has a very long history, but Gtk in-general is not for the faint of heart and GTkSharp is a very thin C# wrapper on top. I have clients still running my  Mono/Gtk apps on Win/Mac/*nix, but for new Windows/macOS apps, I would highly recommend using `Xamarin.Mac` (with or without `Xamarin.Forms` for the UI) and thus UWP on Windows (with or without `Xamarin.Forms` for the UI) : https://blog.xamarin.com/preview-bringing-macos-to-xamarin-forms/

Comment: AFAIK there's no such thing as "VS/Gtk project". Gtk is a widget toolkit and VS is an IDE. There is no direct link between these.

Comment: The IDE is "Visual Studio Community". It has Gtk mode: New solution > Other > .NET > Gtk# 2.0 Project

Comment: GTK# is not part of Xamarin family, but a purely community project. So when you said "just to find out that there is no significant community support to what I'm doing", you should realize without the community it won't exist at all.  If you look for resources to learn it, learn from examples (Banshee/Tomboy are great and complex UI). Unlike commercial products, such open source projects won't have tons of written materials.

Answer (score 2):

Gtk# was one of the first graphic toolkits to become available when Mono saw the light. It works fine on Windows, Mac and Linux, but it is stuck in Gtk v2, while in the moment of writing this answer Gtk version is already 3.

You can use it without fear, since you're guaranteed it will work correctly in all platforms (apart from being not the most updated graphic toolkit). One drawback I've found is that it tightly enforces a very rigid style. You cannot do fancy things like changing colors of buttons, for example. The other drawback is that TreeView's ListView's, GridView's... are all represented by a single class with various possibilities of storage, making it quite complex to grasp, IMHO.

For the latter, I myself created a [TableTextView](https://github.com/baltasarq/GtkUtil), i.e., a simple table with strings as values, which is by far the more common need.

You can find a [nice Gtk# tutorial here](http://zetcode.com/gui/gtksharp/).

Finally, my advice is not to use Glade or the built-in designer. Doing so will tie your code to a given IDE, while programming your interface "by hand" will give more knowledge of the insides of the toolkit.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I was trying to get away from the hand positioning, but you indeed raise good points.

Comment: I'd agree, though there are ways to change button colours and styles, or any widget for that matter. There's the gtk-rc file which you can load into your app's process space on launch (this being a declarative way to define styles and which rendering engine to use) plus there's ways to modify these things at runtime (in v3 the gtk-rc file is css based in v2 it's its own language). It's also got Cairo and Pango which allows you to do what ever you want really. One of my apps (https://www.continuity.kiwi.nz) is entirely built using GTK#.