# ShowDialog() in Mono

Tags: mono, gtk#, showdialog

I have 2 form in Mono.In OnClickEvent of a button in Form1, i want to showDialog Form2 and fetch a answer from Form2.In C# i have this code

```
Form2 F=new Form2();
F.ShowDialog();
int MyAnswer=F.Answer;
```

### But in Mono ShowDialog() function does not exist.

this question mean: i want to show Form2 but Form1 wait for result of Form2

Comment: I would suggest you remove that bold formatting - people may find that offensive and be less willing to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using Gtk.Window you can use Gtk.Dialog and use this code.

```
ResponseType response = ResponseType.None;
using (var dlg = new YesNoDialog ("Title", "Question", "Yes Button", "No Button"))
    response = (ResponseType) dialog.Run ();

if (response == ResponseType.Yes)
        OverwriteFile ();
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to use `System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog()` in a Gtk# application.

The equivalent Gtk# function is called `Gtk.Dialog.Run`, see [Is there a Form.Showdialog equivalent for Gtk# Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990640/is-there-a-form-showdialog-equivalent-for-gtk-windows)

You also need to create a Dialog, not a Form - ie. when you add the new class in MonoDevelop, you choose "Gtk / Dialog", not "Gtk / Widget".